# Raspbian Stretch: WiFi configuration from hotspot

Tags: raspbian, networking

I'm looking for a webserver to configure the network using the AP that works with the latest Raspbian Stretch. If I'm not wrong these projects rely on the old name scheme:

https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf

https://github.com/jasbur/RaspiWiFi

https://github.com/harryallerston/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot

https://github.com/billz/raspap-webgui

https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf

Comment: One problem is `wpa_supplicant.service` fighting with `hostapd`: in the default setup you can have only either-or, which renders the convenient method of Jessie moot, to just plug in an additional Wifi USB adaptor when one needs to update the system via that temporary Internet uplink (e.g., via Phone tethering). See also my open question: https://serverfault.com/questions/869857/systemd-how-to-selectively-disable-wpa-supplicant-for-a-specific-wlan-interface

Comment: An option might be to use wpa_supplicant for AP operation, with `mode=2`. I yet have to try that path. This requires disabling `wpa_supplicant.service` and enabling `wpa_supplicant@.service`. It seems that Debian is hesitant to rely on `wpa_supplicant@.service` at the moment and has left this out, while Arch Linux has included it since several releases. The whole `systemd-networkd` is partly promising, partly an ugly mess.

Comment: What is the official suggestion about configuring WiFi in an headless system? I can't believe they messed up the networking section without thinking how the users will set up the network!

Comment: Is there an official suggestion? It looks, erm, very *headless* (pun intended).

Comment: Raspberry Foundation members told me that we users had twelve months time to prepare for Stretch and don't like to be asked why they removed the Jessie download link from the download page...

Comment: Not sure how much this is going to help but apparently it's possible to restore the old naming system easily, or create a custom one. [This page](https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/raspberry-pi/2208241.htm) (German) has some instructions on it. I'm trying out the `cmdline.txt` option which only adds `net.ifnames=0` to it, with RPI-Wireless-Hotspot right now.

Comment: Goto: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191252 and you will find what you have to do there.